# Third party latitude and longitude are not matching in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have an external json which I am trying to overlay on a google map. The overall plumbing works fine.

The map gets generated. Data gets iterated, and markers are placed by reading the coordinates. But the when i look at the map the coordinates are way off on the map. The data set can not be wrong, i can give my word on that. Is there some adjustment I need to make to get this thing map to each other. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.748433, -73.985655),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script> 
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var image = 'http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/doitt/images/marker.png';
        $.getJSON("http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/jfzu-yy6n.json", function(json1) {
          $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.facility_address.latitude, data.facility_address.longitude); 
            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                title: data.title,
                icon:image
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see the data, both where it is appearing and where you expect it to appear. If you know it what projection it is using.

Comment: You can reference the data from here

http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/jfzu-yy6n.json

I mean I cant pin point a specific location but if you look at the dataset you can see that there are bunch of manhattan locations and none of them are appearing on the map.

Comment: If _none_ of them are appearing on the map, that is a different problem.  Your question stated "the coordinates are way off on the map".

Comment: Your code and json works fine for me on a local copy.

Comment: @geocodezip--thats what I am saying..the data is getting bound but it is not showing accurate locations. And that is what I mean by 'off'..the actual mechanical part of is working fine but maybe the google map is reading the coordinates incorrectly and then putting the markers at the wrong places? That is what I am thinking

Comment: My question is how do I tell what is "off", the points are all close to or on roads.  How do I know where they should be?  If the data was geocoded using a third party geocoder (as the title of your question implies), you can't really expect it to line up perfectly with the map tiles.  The places are not "way off" that I can see, but look reasonable (without more information).

Comment: Well i can tell they are off because the entire island of Manhattan is empty...i see your point that how you say what is off...well let me develop a click on the markers to display the lat/ long info..then maybe i could re address this question again. I think I will leave this question open for the time being. Really appreciate your help man

Comment: "Well i can tell they are off because the entire island of Manhattan is empty" The entire island of Manhattan is empty because none of the facilities in the dataset are actually physically located in Manhattan. 73 of the facilities have owners who's address lies in Manhattan, but that is an entirely different thing than the facility address.

Comment: @astupidname--i located the issue. It is the dataset indeed. The api is releasing 1000 rows/ query. So the first 1000 query is located in the bronx...so right now I am working on to get all the rows and then mapping them. But you are right- the locations on the dataset are not from manhatta